# KOHANA: ORM + MySQL won't find table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orm, kohana

For some reason I see a Kohana exeption `Exception [ 0 ]: The "users" table doesn't exist. Make sure to import the tables.sql file`.
What I need to do?

```
19 {
20  ORM::factory('user');
21 }
22 catch(exception $e)
23 {
24  throw new Exception('The "users" table doesn\'t exist. Make sure to import the tables.sql file');
25 }
26 
27 Route::set('Kohanauserauth', user::path().'(/<action>(/<id>))')
28  -> defaults(array(
29      'controller' => 'Kohanauserauth'
```

Comment: Above line 24 add `echo Database_Exception::text($e);` and that should give you the specific error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine you've enabled the "Auth" module and not set up the database tables beforehand. Auth requires a table called "users". The schema for the tables is included in the module folders. If you're not using the Auth module then disable it in your bootstrap file.

You've not said what version of Kohana you're using so I'll assume 3.3, so I would advise reading this first: http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/auth/

If you're new to Kohana and not willing to invest time in reading the limited documentation, then I would advise using a different framework, because Kohana takes quite a long time to learn.

Comment: Then you have not provided anywhere near enough information in your question.

Comment: You need to try to fix it yourself, and then explain what you have tried, and what the results were. You should not simply post an error message with no context, history or research effort, then expect someone to fix it for you.